Ubuntu doesn't detect just one bluetooth keyboard
On my laptop when I boot with Ubuntu, Ubuntu discovers other Bluetooth devices but not my Samsung Smart Trio 500 Bluetooth keyboard but it used to detect and pair with the keyboard. And the Bluetooth keyboard is detected and working on the same laptop when I boot to Windows. It is that, this Ubuntu stopped even finding and showing MAC address only for this keyboard when I "scan on" with bluetoothctl. What could be the real issue here?

I cannot add a manufacturer link because the Samsung site is stupid. Every time I try to set the language, it returns to my native language - no chance to set it to english.
